# Read File Sequentially and pass it to Multiple Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a huge file, which has around 1 million records present in it.
My requirement is to read records from file and have a configurable number of threads which process them across multiple threads.

Currently, I am reading that file using a single thread and storing it into a collection.

How can I pass the collection elements sequentially to different threads for further processing?

Comment: How about [blocking Qeue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) ?

Comment: @Babel could you please explain more in detail

Comment: there should be tutorials online that explain it in more detail

Answer (score 0):

Okay !!

Your requirement seems more or less a Producer Consumer Paradigm [Producer Consumer Paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem). 
If you are using java 1.5 and above you can achieve using concurrent collections.

```
BlockingQueue sharedQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
//You can select any Collection Object above which implements BlockingQueue
```

You can find other class which implements   [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)

Okay !! Here your Reading chunks of your file will be stored in your `sharedQueue` that means your reading logic will act as a Producer.

**for example in your reading file thread:**

```
 @Override
public void run() {

    // read your file and put reading chunks in Queue 
       sharedQueue.put(yourReadingCHunk);
}
```

In your consumer thread you will try to get those chunks from that Queue.

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {
                System.out.println("Consumed: "+ sharedQueue.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            }
        }
    }
```

The only thing is you have to pass that `shareQueue` while creating threads 
 something like below.

```
   Thread iamreading= new Thread(new YourReadingFileClass(sharedQueue));
   Thread iamUsing = new Thread(new YourUsingFileClass(sharedQueue));
```

For more about Producer and Consumer problem Using this [Link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/02/producer-consumer-design-pattern-with.html)